# How to call a modal controller when clicking on a google map marker in ionic 5

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, modal-dialog

I need to have a feature in which when the user clicks on the marker on a google maps, all the info related to that marker is displayed on the a modal. This feature was fairly straight forward in ionic 3 but I am not able to do it in ionic 5. Whenever I call command to create a modal, I get error  Cannot read property 'create' of undefined. Please help me out. Below is my function.
`

```
marker.addListener('click',function(){
let that = this;
console.log("station id..", this.title);
this.station_id = this.title;
const modal =  that.modalCtrl.create({
component: BarrageDetailModalPage,
animated: true,
 mode: 'ios',
 backdropDismiss: false,
cssClass:'edit-modal',
componentProps: {
 "station_id": this.title,
}
 });
modal.onDidDismiss().then(()=>{
 this.get_user_log();
})
return modal.present();
});
```

`

Comment: This would be how to use the `ModalController` in Ionic 5. https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal#usage

Comment: @AldinBradaric I gone through the documentation and I am using the modal controller in other function as well. The only one not working is when I click on the marker in google maps

Comment: Could you add the initialization of your ModalController? The async keywords are missing, as per the docs, so I'm a tad surprised that the other one's working.

Comment: I can't at async inside a function. can only use it when declaring a function. It throws error that modifiers can't be declared here